# ' VS " in javascript

Tags: javascript, react-native, realm

I am using Realm in react native.

Here's my code.

```
 const filter = "t BEGINSWITH 'A'";
 const markers = realm.objects(Town.schema.name).filtered(filter);
```

The above code is not working.
But if I change the filter code like this:

```
 const filter = 't BEGINSWITH "A"';
```

Then it works charm.

What's the difference between ' and " in javascript?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Afaik nothing, but maybe there is one in the meta language you are using.

Comment: Thanks for your support.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no difference between `'` and `"` in JavaScript (other than the obvious that `'` may exist escaped inside `"`-quoted strings and vice versa).

There apparently *is* a difference between `'` and `"` in the Realm query language: namely, that double-quotes must be used to represent strings.

See the [Realm documentation on filtering](https://realm.io/docs/javascript/latest/#filtering) which uses double-quotes for strings with `BEGINSWITH`:

> ```
> let tanDogs = dogs.filtered('color = "tan" AND name BEGINSWITH "B"');
> ```